# Windows 10 inbox will not sync

Tags: windows-10, email, sync, windows-10-mail-app

Windows 10 inbox mail app will not sync emails. It worked when I first installed windows however it will no longer sync. When I press sync I get the animation that goes forever.

When I press manage account settings, change something then press "done", it sits there with the loading animation forever and never completes. This occurs with all inbox accounts.

I have tried uninstalling the application and reinstalling via these instructions with no luck.

Powershell:
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps | Remove-AppxPackage

Restart

Reinstall.

These instructions did not clear my remembered account however.

edit: When I go to settings -> email & app accounts I get the loading animation forever as well.

How can I delete all of my mail accounts from powershell/cmd line?

edit: I deleted my accounts and added them again. It seemed to work at first downloading about 50% of my emails and now the problem is back and email will no longer sync.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue using outlook 2016 with imap configuration, check this links:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10/outlook-2016-imap-issues-for-inbox/701134b1-0e66-4c47-ac47-9e7125691866

Comment: Can you explain the answer better? I can't figure out what the solution is from the link, it is just people saying they have a problem?